# Best Practice: Accessing radio button group

Tags: javascript, forms, dom, getelementsbyname

Looking for the best, standards compliant, cross browser compatible, forwards compatible way to access a group of radio buttons in the DOM (this is closely related to my other most recent post...), without the use of any external libraries.

```
<input type="radio" value="1" name="myRadios" />One<br />
<input type="radio" value="2" name="myRadios" />Two<br />
```

I've read conflicting information on getElementsByName(), which seems like the proper way to do this, but I'm unclear if this is a standards compliant, forwards compatible solution.  Perhaps there is a better way?

Comment: +1 for being specific, I like that in questions.

Comment: As an aside: those radio <input>s are both dying for a <label>. :)

Comment: Yeah, I know, I was just being concise...

Answer (score 2):

I'm not totally happy with this solution, but I did finally track this down in the Gecko DOM documentation.

*name gets or sets the name attribute of an DOM object, it only applies to the following elements: anchor, applet, form, frame, iframe, image, input, map, meta, object, option, param, select and textarea.*

```
HTMLElement.name = string;
var elName = HTMLElement.name;

var fControl = HTMLFormElement.elementName;
var controlCollection = HTMLFormElement.elements.elementName;
```

More here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.name

So I suppose this is *a* standards compliant way of proceeding (though a best practice may not really exist...)

```
document.getElementById('myForm').elements.myRadios
```

Comment: `document.forms.elements.myRadios`

Answer (score 0):

I think the best thing going forwards is:

```
form.elements.myRadios
```

vs

```
form.myRadios
```

The reason being that according to the latest [spec](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/Overview.html), `elements.someName` will return an object of `RadioNodeList` (if multiple elements have the same name) that contains a `value` attribute indicating the checked item's value.

`form.myradios` on the other hand will return an object of `NodeList` which is just an ordered collection of items, and does not have any `value` property.

Finding the checked items in radios and checkboxes has traditionally been a very painful exercise.

However, I am not sure how would we access all checked elements for checkboxes. Couldn't find that in the spec. Hope that is not missing.

Comment: use `form.elements<name>` not `form<name>`